# kafka connect in distributed mode is not generating logs specified via log4j properties

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

I have been using `Kafka Connect` in my work setup for a while now and it works perfectly fine.
Recently I thought of dabbling with few connectors of my own in my docker based kafka cluser with just one broker (ubuntu:18.04 with kafka installed) and a separate node acting as client for deploying connector apps.

**Here is the problem:**
Once my broker is up and running, I login to the **client** node (*with no broker running,just the vanilla kafka installation*), i setup the class path to point to my connector libraries. Also the `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS` environment variable to point to the location of log file to generate with debug mode enabled.
So every time i start the kafka worker using command:

> nohup /opt//bin/connect-distributed /opt//config/connect-distributed.properties > /dev/null 2>&1 &

the connector starts running, but I don't see the log file getting generated.
I have tried several changes but nothing works out.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Does this mean that *connect-distributed.sh* doesn't generate the log file after reading the variable 
  `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS`? and if it does, could someone explain how?

**NOTE**:
(I have already debugged the *connect-distributed.sh* script and tried the options where daemon mode is included and not included, by default if `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS` is not provided, it uses the `connect-log4j.properties` file in config directory, but even then no log file is getting generated).

**OBSERVATION**:

Only when I start zookeeper/broker on the client node, then provided `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS` value is picked and logs start getting generated but nothing related to the Kafka connector. *I have already verified the connectivity b/w the client and the broker using **kafkacat***

***The interesting part is:***
The same process i follow in my workpalce and logs start getting generated every time the worker (`connnect-distributed.sh`) is started, but I haven't' been to replicate the behaviors in my own setup). And I have no clue what I am missing here.
Could someone provide some reasoning, this is really driving me mad.

Comment: Please provide what do you set to `KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS`

Comment: export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///u01/shared_data/connect-azuresql-log4j.properties"

echo $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS

Comment: what's in the `connect-azuresql-log4j.properties` file?

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, traceFile

log4j.appender.traceFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.traceFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.traceFile.File=/u01/shared_data/logs_dir/connect-worker.log
log4j.appender.traceFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.traceFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR

Comment: this log file is only generated when broker or zookeeper runs on the node where i am running the worker. just running the worker with remote broker is not generating the log file.

Comment: Kafka Connect does indeed make logs. I've personally tested it